# Strange View.getHitRect() behaviour

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have a simple layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="animate"
    android:text="animate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in my Activity I am printing hit rect of button after changing its `y`location:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void animate(View view) {
    printHitRect();
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setY(50);
    printHitRect();
}
private void printHitRect() { 
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    findViewById(R.id.button1).getHitRect(rect);
    Log.d(">>button1 hit rect", rect.flattenToString()); 
} 
}
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

> > > button1 hit rect: 0 0 116 72
> > >
> > > button1 hit rect: 0 50 116 122

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

> > > button1 hit rect: 0 0 116 72
> > >
> > > button1 hit rect: -58 14 58 86

Can someone explain this output, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? Basically I am using this `getHitRect()` in my custom `ViewGroup` to detect which child user has touched. Is there a better way to get the child at a particular point, may be a function like `getChildAt(x, y)`?

Instead of `setY()`, I have tried `setTranslateY()`. I also have used NineOldAndroid library as well as built in animation framework. Same behaviour can be seen if I use `findViewById(R.id.button1).animate().y(50)` instead of `setY()`.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up writing utility method using nineoldandroid library that is working now:

```
private static void getHitRect(View v, Rect rect) {
    rect.left = (int) com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper.getX(v);
    rect.top = (int) com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper.getY(v);
    rect.right = rect.left + v.getWidth();
    rect.bottom = rect.top + v.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getHitRect()` had a bug and would not apply transforms properly. We fixed this bug internally and the fix will be made available in the next public release of Android.

Comment: Since this answer was made on July 19 2013, I'm assuming that you were referring to Android 4.3 as the "next release". Does this mean the method, getHitRect() is unreliable on versions prior to it?

Comment: @Saket I'd say that's a fair assumption as I have a phone here which is stuck on 4.1.2 (Xperia S) and the y coordinates I am getting dont make much sense, i.e. bottom and top - bummer because that rect function would have saved me a lot of pain...

Comment: @Saket thanks for the hint, I actually ended up doing that :) !

Comment: Would be great if this could be added to the documentation, because on lower than 4.3 the bug is still present.

Answer (score 2):

You can get hit rect by this way:

```
public Rect getHitRect(View child){
   Rect frame = new Rect();
   frame.left = child.getLeft();
   frame.right = child.getRight();
   frame.top = child.getTop();
   frame.bottom = child.getBottom();
   return frame;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work as child.getLeft() returns wrong value, the solution the questioner wrote using nineoldandroid works

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't depend on NineOldAndroids.

If you follow the code path for NineOldAndroids code path you eventually get here on post honeycomb devices: [Github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/blob/9f20fd77e04942fd50b95aeb1c492a38e36c06dd/library/src/com/nineoldandroids/view/animation/AnimatorProxy.java)

```
private static void getHitRect(View v, Rect rect) {
    rect.left = (int) (v.getLeft() + v.getTranslationX());
    rect.top = (int) (v.getTop() + v.getTranslationY());
    rect.right = rect.left + v.getWidth();
    rect.bottom = rect.top + v.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: Good solution, I just have to add small calibration `rect.top -= dividerValue/2; rect.bottom +=dividerValue/2;`   as when using wider divider between items in listview, there was a lot of missed detections of touches.