# Modification of SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener to support swipe or drag to open/close

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

I'm modifying the following code:

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java

First I'm just trying to drag the child of a listview wherever the touch is pointing. But after applying it once it seems my future taps on listview gets messed up and I'm unable to move that child again. It acts as if listview is not properly receiving the touch anymore or it feels the listview is not receiving touches anymore.

I see similar behaviour if I modify the above code directly and comment out the method calls that dismiss a cell from list view. Following is my starter code:

```
public class ListItemSwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener  
{
    private String TAG = "ListItemSwipeListener";
    // Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
    private int mSlop;
    private long mAnimationTime;

    private boolean mPaused;
    private boolean mSwiping;

    // Fixed properties
    private ListView mListView;
    private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

    // Transient properties
    private float mDownX;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private View mDownView;

    public ListItemSwipeListener(ListView listView)
    {
        this.mListView = listView;

        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mAnimationTime = listView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
    {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) 
        {
            mViewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
        }

        switch(motionEvent.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                if (mPaused)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
                int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
                mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                View child;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        mDownView = child;                        
                        Log.d(TAG, "index: "+i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mDownView != null) {
                    mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();                    

                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);                    
                }

                return false;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused)
                {
                    break;
                }
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) 
                {
                    mSwiping = true;
                }

                if (mSwiping)
                {
                    mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX);

                    return true;
                }
                break;                
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) 
                {
                    break;
                }                           

                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;                  
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownView = null;                   
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() 
    {
        return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
        };
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) 
    {
        mPaused = !enabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out getHitRect() in Android is buggy once a view has been translated, the solution is here:
[Strange View.getHitRect() behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750116/strange-view-gethitrect-behaviour)